Resolve package conflicts in LaTeX: ! LaTeX Error: Command ..... already defined
Considering this thread there is a discussion where an user give an answer to solve conflicts between packages.
\let\oldsecond\second 
\let\olddegree\degree
\let\second\relax
\let\degree\relax
\usepackage{conflictingpackage}
\let\second\oldsecond
\let\degree\olddegree

I haven't found this package conflictingpackage in CTAN, but I have found these:

noconflict – Resolve macro name conflict between packages;


savesym – Redefine symbols where names conflict.

Generally when something is defined I write
\let<command>\relax 

to continue the compilation. There are cases where this procedure does not work.

Is there a procedure that must be followed?

How can the previous packages which have I pointed out help the user?

But noconflict and savesym how them can be used?



conflictingpackage is not the name of a package it is just a meta-variable standing in for the name of whichever package is conflicting

clearly there is no general procedure. if you have two packages that define the same command then you have to make a choice of keeping one package working and breaking the other. You can avoid the error on load by renaming one of them, but then every use of the command in the document you have to individually decide whether to keep the old name or use the new name, depending on which package version you need in that case.

@DavidCarlisle Thanks for your contribution. I won’t delete the question; maybe someone else will want to answer, and it might be useful. But noconflict and savesym how them can be used?

No idea. But your statement "Generally....  sounds as if you consider package conflict to be normal. The only general advice is do not load conflicting packages. In some cases you may be able to locally avoid conflicts but not in general.

"Is there a procedure that must be followed?"  Undoubtedly, one should be "Only load the packages that you really, really, really need".
